# How to play video from Red5 server in Android 4.0+？

Tags: android, red5, rtmp

Are there some available component or demos that support red5 rtmp streaming?I prepare to set about a secondary development in android which will be used in Graduation Project

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an RTMP library or something like JavaCV. If you have the coding skills you can actually use the built-in MediaCodec to decode h.264 / AAC; the tricky part is that Android doesn't include the RTMP decoder / demuxer; this is where JavaCV or an alternate RTMP library come in. If you want to dig into the red5-client code you could also try that to decode the RTMP, but that may be a good deal of work.

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml

Lastly, you could just use Adobe AIR.

Comment: Thanks.I'm always seeking the library like JavaCV,which looks like Opencv which is coded by C/C++.While red5-client seems too difficult.Once again,thanks.